# How to check if the PODs exists in namespace if not, Run the playbook command to deploy the resources

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I am trying to write a playbook which needs to

1. check if the resources exists in a namespace.
2. If not, 'deploy' it and if exists 'skip' the deployment as it is already available.

I am able to achieve the skip step but not the deploy step if is not exists.

```
- name: To check if the resource exists
  shell: |
    set -e -o pipefail;
    kubectl get pods -n test | grep postgres
  changed_when: false
  register: checkpod
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
- name: Print checkpod
  debug:
    msg: "{{ checkpod.stdout_lines }}"

- name: Task to run the optional to install postgres
  shell: ansible-playbook -i ~/playbooks/deploy.yml
  when: checkpod | length == 0
```

My error is this

```
 "stderr": "No resources found in ama namespace.", "stderr_lines": ["No resources found in test namespace."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Comment: Instead of using a `shell` command, use the purposed module: [`kubernetes.core.k8s_info`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/k8s_info_module.html), this way, you won't have to rewrite the logic that would make the command recover from an exit status different than zero (which is what you are facing right now).

Comment: My ansible version is 2.9.10 and it looks it doesn't support
`
i get an error as "ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'kubernetes.core.k8s_info'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path."
`                                                                                                                                         `
- name: To check if the resource exists
  kubernetes.core.k8s_info:
    kind: Pod
    namespace: ama
  register: pod_list
`@β.εηοιτ.βε

Comment: @lakshman You should install the collection `ansible-galaxy collection install kubernetes.core`

Comment: @khaled I shouldn't install module on the k8s cluster as it is managed through ansible and rancher. I got it achieved using the ''failed_when" instead of changed_when

Comment: Thanks for the inputs my solution is working without the module

Comment: To simplify this even further, if you `kubectl apply` Deployments and similar objects that already exist without modifications, the cluster won't do anything ("you asked for a Deployment running 3 replicas of `registry.example.com/image`, and that's the state we're in right now").  So you should be able to unconditionally run the deployment without needing to check first.

Comment: @DavidMaze Can you provide an example for it. I don't get you clearly. Eventhough i got the error fixed but still i wish to know what your suggestion is?